# How to pass data from Angular 9 UI to .Net 3.1 controller

Tags: .net, angular, http, post

I've tried:

1. adding CORS code to the startup as suggested in several places
2. making sure the angular .ts object properties match the .net object
   properties, spelling and case

I put a console.log in the angular code and the object is getting populated, but when code hits the break point on the Controller, the object is always null.

Below is the angular and .Net code ... what else can I try or retry?

```
    //.net class
    public class AccountLookupRequest
    {
         public string FILENO { get; set; }
         public string AccountName { get; set; }
         public string SSN { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    //angular class
    export class AccountLookupRequest{
    
      public FILENO: string;
      public AccountName: string;
      public SSN: string;
    
      constructor() { }
    }


//angular service
////try1
//getAccounts(accountlookup: AccountLookupRequest) {
//  //log the input
//  console.log('accountlookup', accountlookup);
//  //serialize accountlookup object to json
//  return this.http.post<any>(this._AccountLookup, accountlookup)
//    .pipe(
//      map(response => {
//        console.log('response', response);
//        return response;
//      })
//    );
//}

//try2
getAccounts(accountlookup: AccountLookupRequest):Observable<any> {
  console.log('accountlookup', accountlookup);
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };
  return this.http.post(this._AccountLookup, accountlookup, httpOptions);
}


//.net controller 

        //try1 - jsonInput var is null
        //public IActionResult GetAccounts(string jsonInput) 
        //{
        //    List<AccountLookupResponse> results = new List<AccountLookupResponse>();
        //    try
        //    {
        //        AccountLookupRequest input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountLookupRequest>(jsonInput);
        //        results = _clsRepo.GetAccounts(input);
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception ex)
        //    {
        //        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new { Message = $"{ex.Message}\n\n{ex.StackTrace}" });
        //    }
        //    return Ok(results);
        //}

        //try2 - request var is null
        public IActionResult GetAccounts([FromBody] AccountLookupRequest request) 
        {
            List<AccountLookupResponse> results = new List<AccountLookupResponse>();
            try
            {
                results = _clsRepo.GetAccounts(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new { Message = $"{ex.Message}\n\n{ex.StackTrace}" });
            }
            return Ok(results);
        }
```

NOTE1: I also tried adding [HttpPost] to the Controller, and that had no effect.

NOTE2: I tried the following in the service and it did "work", but since I had to change it to a "get" it doesn't seem like a real solution.

```
//try3
getAccounts(request: AccountLookupRequest): Observable<any> {
  console.log('in staffservice.ts , accountlookup', request);
  const jsontAccountLookup = JSON.stringify(request);
  let myParams = new HttpParams();
  myParams = myParams.append('jsontAccountLookup', jsontAccountLookup);
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }),
    params: myParams
  };
  return this.http.get(this._AccountLookup, httpOptions);
}

//and changed the controller method signature to 
public IActionResult GetAccounts(string jsontAccountLookup)
{ //code to DeserializeObject  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not specified its a post request that might be the problem!

```
//  [Route("<<enter route also if needed>>")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetAccounts([FromBody] AccountLookupRequest request) 
    {
        List<AccountLookupResponse> results = new List<AccountLookupResponse>();
        try
        {
            results = _clsRepo.GetAccounts(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new { Message = $"{ex.Message}\n\n{ex.StackTrace}" });
        }
        return Ok(results);
    }
```

Comment: I had already tried the [HttpPost] .. did not help